# Liquid Sim Stationary Effectors

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a literal Blender fluid simulation.  I’m struggling to get the fluid to settle back down after being thrown around by a blade and vortex force field. It also seems to increase in volume over time.  Decreasing the particle radius to .7 has helped, but any smaller it flies through the jar. I have an effector thickness on the jar of .004m and sampling dubsteps of the jar around 3-5 steps.  Do substeps of stationary effector help the liquid not fall threw?  And do substeps make the liquid tend to hang on the surface a little more?
Also, if a sim is running well at 32 resolution and .7 particle radius.  Is it possible that I may not need to run the smaller particle radius at higher resolution?

Comment: There can be two containers one that is rendered and seen in your final image and one that is [thicker] and used for the fluid simulation obstacle.

Comment: The thicker obstacle is not rendered.  That is a single click option in Blender.  The thicker obstacle may contain the fluid better.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  That's exactly what I ended up doing!  Now I just need to figure out how to fluid particle instances keyframed to an .abc file.  If I simply export them using the checkbox (include particles) each particle comes in to Keyshot as its own animation(thousands) and they all start on frame 1.  I saw some Python scripts for v2.8, but they didn't run in 2.9 and I know almost nothing about Python coding.  I wish there were an Add On specifically for this.  Maybe I am just better off learning to rendering in Blender.